# How do I know which repositories are taking up my LFS bandwidth on Github?

Tags: github

I got an email from GitHub telling me that my GitHub LFS bandwidth quota is over. I wanted to check which repositories are responsible for this high bandwidth. So I went to Settings -> Billing:

[image]

At the bottom of this page, I  see that my quota is 1 GB and the usage is 1.14 GB, and there is a link for purchasing more quota:

[image]

But there is no way to see which repositories are responsible for this high quota.

I clicked "Get Usage Report" on the top-right of the page, but received an email with an empty CSV file.

Is there a way to find this information in GitHub website?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Tracking storage and bandwidth use](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage)?

Comment: @Rubén I read this, but it just tells in general about the quotas - it does not tell me how to see the quota by repository.